# refresh OfflineIMAP on command

Tags: gmail, imap, mutt

I need help writing a script to update offlineIMAP on demand.

It will need to interrupt an already running instance of offlineIMAP, run an offlineIMAP sync, and then proceed with the normal sync updates every five minutes. (autorefresh = 5)

A situation is that I have mutt and offlineIMAP running. I can hear my phone receive mail, but I cannot respond via mutt until offlineIMAP runs the sync.

OfflineIMAP - http://offlineimap.org/

Comment: @Celada can you recommend one?

Comment: There is [fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/) but it is a little different in that it doesn't copy IMAP to IMAP but rather receives from IMAP and injects to a local MTA. Maybe that would work for you?

Comment: I moved from fetchmail to offlineimap so I could use imap with maildir. Buuuuuut I just found a soultion to my problem with your help. offlineimap does now support idle. http://superuser.com/questions/483006/offlineimap-turn-idle-on